# ребят как поменять обои через python

Tags: python

есть такая проблема, есть папка с программой нужно сделать, что бы по кнопки менялся фон, если пишу

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, "C:/Users/Dmitriy/Desktop/fon/win.jpg" , 0)
```

то все работает, но нужно сделать так `ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, "fon/win.jpg" , 0)`
не работает.
нужно именно так сделать, или как то по-другому, что бы работал на разных компах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А Вы уверены, что папка Desktop на всех компах находится в домашней папке пользователя?
Если да, то попробуйте так:

```py
import ctypes
from pathlib import Path

desktop = Path().home().joinpath('Desktop')

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, desktop.joinpath('fon/win.jpg').as_posix(), 0)
                                                                                # ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### UPD

> Послето того, как выяснилось, что файл с изображением находится в папке со скриптом

```py
# Если файл изображения в той же папке что и скрипт то `.joinpath('fon')` не нужно
img_dir = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath('fon')

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, img_dir.joinpath('win.jpg').as_posix(), 0)
```

Comment: Возникла ошибка File "C:\Users\Dmitriy\Desktop\Программа\0.103.py", line 175, in winrt
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, desktop.joinpath('fon/win.jpg'), 3)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 3

Comment: @ДмитрийИршинский, чуть поменял. попробуйте

Comment: Не нашел файл, черный экран. Таже проблема осталась

Comment: @ДмитрийИршинский, попробуйте добавить `print(desktop)` и посмотрите как выглядит путь поиска

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение, что Ваша папка Desktop  может находиться в папке OneDrive (это к тому, что я писал в самом начале ответа)

Comment: C:\Users\Dmitriy\Desktop

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135617/discussion-between-namerek-and--).

Comment: Тут смотри мне надо сделать так. У меня есть файл py  в папке  и в этой же папке картинка, все это на флешке. Мне надо допустим перенести флеш на другой компьютер и нажать на py и картинка поменять. Но я призван к директории e, если флешка будет f, то py не запустит

Comment: @ДмитрийИршинский обновил